# Changing the scale of Rectangle using storyboard

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, storyboard

I want to change the scale of Rectangle using storyboard, I don't know why it doesn't work. Looking forward to anyone's reply! The C# code is:

```
Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
InitializeComponent();
DoubleAnimation daScaleX = new DoubleAnimation();
daScaleX.From = 1;
daScaleX.To = 2;
daScaleX.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);

DoubleAnimation daScaleY = new DoubleAnimation();
daScaleY.From = 1;
daScaleY.To = 2;
daScaleY.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);

BounceEase easing = new BounceEase()
{
    EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseOut
};

daScaleX.EasingFunction = easing;
daScaleY.EasingFunction = easing;

Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(daScaleX, new PropertyPath("ScaleX"));
Storyboard.SetTarget(daScaleX, st);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(daScaleY, new PropertyPath("ScaleY"));
Storyboard.SetTarget(daScaleY, st);

sb.Children.Add(daScaleX);
sb.Children.Add(daScaleY);
sb.Begin();
```

The XAML file is:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
      <Rectangle x:Name="rect" Fill="Blue" Width="200" Height="40" Margin="5" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform x:Name="st" ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
            </TransformGroup>
        </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
      </Rectangle>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this below code separately..it works for me

```
   <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <Rectangle x:Name="rect" Fill="Blue" Width="200" Height="40" Margin="5" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                    <ScaleTransform x:Name="st" ScaleX="1.0" ScaleY="1.0"></ScaleTransform>
                </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            </Rectangle>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

and did this animation on windows loaded event

```
void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();   

        DoubleAnimation daScaleX = new DoubleAnimation();
        daScaleX.From = 1;
        daScaleX.To = 2;
        daScaleX.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300);

        DoubleAnimation daScaleY = new DoubleAnimation();
        daScaleY.From = 1;
        daScaleY.To = 2;
        daScaleY.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300);

        BounceEase easing = new BounceEase()
        {
            EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseOut
        };

        daScaleX.EasingFunction = easing;
        daScaleY.EasingFunction = easing;

        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(daScaleX, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.ScaleX"));
        Storyboard.SetTarget(daScaleX, rect);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(daScaleY, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.ScaleY"));
        Storyboard.SetTarget(daScaleY, rect);

        sb.Children.Add(daScaleX);
        sb.Children.Add(daScaleY);
        sb.Begin();
    }
```